# VueJS: bypass beforeRouteLeave

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue SPA. Inside a component, I use `beforeRouteLeave` guard to prevent the user from accidentally leaving the page. Within that component, sometimes I fire an ajax request, which on success it must redirect the page to another location.

The problem is once ajax requests succeeds and `$router.push()` attempts to perform the redirect, `beforeRouteLeave` does not allow it.

How can I temporarily bypass `beforeRouteLeave` and leave the `$router` perform the redirect?

```
<script>

methods:{
    someAjaxCall()
    {
        axios.post('...')
        .then(res=>{
            this.$router.push({
                name: 'route.name.here'
            })
        })
    }
},

beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next){
    next(window.confirm('Are you sure? Progress will be discarded.'))
},

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can use a boolean variable with condition to bypass the guard:

```
<script>

data(){
    return {
        avoidRouteLeave: false,
    }
},
methods:{
    someAjaxCall()
    {
        axios.post('...')
        .then(res=>{
            this.avoidRouteLeave = true
            this.$router.push({
                name: 'route.name.here'
            })
        })
    }
},

beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next){
    if(this.avoidRouteLeave)
        next()
    else
        next(window.confirm('Are you sure? Progress will be discarded.'))
},

</script>
```